# Quitar numeral molesto en commandLink (JSF)

Tags: jsf, jsp

Estoy probando un poco un framework de Java Server Pages (JSP) que se llama Java Server Faces (JSF). Hice una plantilla base y otras plantillas cliente. La pagina es bien sencilla, pero hay un tema que no logro solucionar, y es este:

A mi izquierda tengo un div, que contiene un form con el icono (o "logo") de la pagina y debajo los links (). Resulta que cuando obtengo el texto del link por mi Bean (o incluso si lo escribo directamente en value), al final de la cadena me aparece un "(#)".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y en mi etiquetado yo nunca he puesto eso por ningun lado...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="blueprint/screen.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="blueprint/print.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>      
    <title><h:outputText value="Pagina principal de la prueba!"></h:outputText></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="esqueleto">
    <div id="top" class="span-24 Last">
        <h:outputText value="Dan Java Server Faces Test"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span-24 Last">
        <div id="left" class="span-8">
            <h:form>
                <div id="mLogo"><h:graphicImage library="images" name="Evil-Smile.png"/></div>
                <div id="item"><h:commandLink value="Primera pagina" action="#{pageControler.Primera()}"/></div>
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="span-16 Last">
            <div id="contenido">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="span-24 Last">
        Bottom
    </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Pense que eran temas de CSS del text-decoration, y como ya lo pueden ver, lo he colocado como "none", pero no. Como me deshago de este molesto "(#)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, di con la solucion del problema. Y resulta ser que lo que me estaba fastidiando los links sorpresivamente era un framework... el Blueprint. Me faltaba declarar un atributo mas llamado "media".

Asi es que se debio llamar desde un principio:

```
<link href="css/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">
 <link href="css/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```